# VBA Randomizing Function to change cell formula using variables, named ranges, and indirect functions

Tags: vba, excel, random

I've been searching and searching and can't find a proper way to do this. I'm using multiple variables and values to set the value of another cell.

I use this formula to accomplish what I need right now in cell "E4" on Sheet "Turn_Travel";

```
=LOOKUP(RAND(),INDEX(INDIRECT("Region"&VLOOKUP($B$4,RegionListTable,MATCH("Region #",RegionListHeader,0),FALSE)&$C$4&"Info"),0,MATCH("Perct.",INDIRECT($C$4&"Header"),0)),INDEX(INDIRECT("Region"&VLOOKUP($B$4,RegionListTable,MATCH("Region #",RegionListHeader,0),FALSE)&$C$4&"Info"),0,MATCH("Weather",INDIRECT($C$4&"Header"),0)))
```

Right now I just hit F9 and it refreshes my worksheet and generates a new Random number which changes my result.

I'm trying to use VBA to generate the Random number and then have the cell "E4" on Sheet "Turn_Travel" contain the above formula with the VBA variable for the Random number.

This was my attempt but I'm getting an error. Can someone spot where I'm going wrong?

```
 Sub TravelRoll()

     Randomize
     Dim TheRoll As Long
     TheRoll = ((1 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
     Worksheets("Turn_Travel").Range("E4").Formula = "=LOOKUP("&TheRoll&",INDEX(INDIRECT(""Region""&VLOOKUP($B$4,RegionListTable,MATCH(""Region #"",RegionListHeader,0),FALSE)&$C$4&""Info""),0,MATCH(""Perct."",INDIRECT($C$4&""Header""),0)),INDEX(INDIRECT(""Region""&VLOOKUP($B$4,RegionListTable,MATCH(""Region #"",RegionListHeader,0),FALSE)&$C$4&""Info""),0,MATCH(""Weather"",INDIRECT($C$4&""Header""),0)))"

 End Sub
```

Comment: It might be irrelevant but how you tried putting space before and after & like this `(" & TheRoll & ",`

Comment: Wow, that was too simple. lol. Thank you. Also, I need my Rnd variable to be between 0 and 1. I don't think my current formula is correct. Is that done correctly?

Comment: First of all you need to declare it as double. If you declare it as long you get 0 or 1. Secondly, you can use `Rnd(1)` to have a random number between 0 and 1. If you want to have limited decimals, for example 2 decimals, you can use `Format(Rnd(1), "#0.00")`

Comment: "I'm getting an error" isn't very specific. You should include the fact that it's a compile-time error, as well as the exact message, and what statement/token the VBE highlights when it complains about your code.

Comment: @Mat's Mug yeah I thought editor might have auto corrected it, so I answered cautiously.

Comment: Yuck. Yuck. Yuck. You are creating a maintenance headache. See if you can do it on a worksheet with no VBA and no indirect calls.

Answer (score 2):

You should have space before and after string concatenation operator (&).

Also you need to declare your variable as double to get numbers between 0 and 1. If you declare it as long you get 0 or 1.

You can use `Rnd` to have a random number between 0 and 1.

If you want to have limited decimals, for example 2 decimals, you can use `Format(Rnd, "#0.00")`

Comment: You can actually simply call `Rnd` (no parameters), the function returns a number between 0 and 1. [This post](http://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-rnd-function.html) explains the parameter: any number greater than 0 will result in the next random number in the sequence.